# difference between ^/(.*) and ^(.*) and .* in the Apache RewriteRule Pattern

Tags: regex, apache, redirect

As far as I know, they are all the same.
But I wonder why people use the `rex` in the `RewriteRule` Pattern.

Does `^` have any performance benefits?

```
RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
```

Does `/` have any performance benefits?

```
RewriteRule /(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
```

Does `()` have any benefits?

```
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
```

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tested these to find the answer to any of your questions yet?

Comment: @TylerH, not exactly! I think it depends on the programming style of a programmer.

Answer (score 2):

> Does ^ have any performance benefits?

Yes, the regex will only apply to the begining of the url so it will be faster

> Does / have any performance benefits?

Not really, it just matches a slash character

> Does () have any benefits?

In regex the parenthesis create a group to capture substrings

Answer (score 0):

There are few more things to keep in mind here (in addition to the other answer):

1. This rule, as it is (alone, without any other rewrites or conditions), should probably be written as

   ```
    Redirect / https://example.com/
   ```

   In  this case, the rewrite engine will not be involved which might result in 
   (probably negligible) performance benefit.
2. If you have a reason to use `%{SERVER_NAME}`, keep in mind that `%{SERVER_NAME}` might have different value than you expect, if [UseCanonicalName](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#usecanonicalname) is set to a non-default value. `%{HTTP_HOST}` should be safer.
3. Even if you have to use `RewriteRules` (or `RewriteCond`), there is no need to use regex to capture full request URI, it is already available in `%{REQUEST_URI}`, so this should be faster:

   ```
   RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
   ```
4. Keep in mind that [RewriteRule](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) behaves differently when use used in `.htaccess` compared to `.conf`:

   > In per-directory context (Directory or .htaccess), the *Pattern* is
   >   matched against only a partial path: the directory path where the rule
   >   is defined is stripped from the path before comparison - up to and
   >   including a trailing slash!. The removed prefix always ends with a
   >   slash, meaning the matching occurs against a string which never has a
   >   leading slash.

   Or to put it more clearly: in `.htaccess`, there is no leading `/`.( just a reminder: you [should not](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html#when) use `.htaccess` at all if you have access to Apache configuration files)